# Recursively tracking state of customers (Presto SQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have one table with the current state_id of my customers and another table holding all states and their state_ids, but without the corresponding customer_id. However, the historical state table holds the information of which state_id it replaced. Hence, it should be possible to recursively track the states/journey of the customer.

Consider the following example:

"Customer" table:

```
customer_id    state_created      current_state_id
1              2017-11-09         33
2              2018-04-01         243
3              2018-07-10         254
```

"Historical_state" table:

```
state_name     replace_state_id   state_id           state_created
State1                            22                 2015-10-08
State1                            211                2017-06-28
State3                            254                2018-07-10
State4         211                243                2018-04-01
State5         22                 33                 2017-11-09
```

I am interested in getting the historical state information on every customer, ie. the following table:

```
customer_id    state_created      state_name       
1              2015-10-00         State1
1              2017-11-09         State5
2              2017-06-28         State1
2              2018-04-01         State4
3              2018-07-10         State3
```

The data is replaced in AWS' Athena, so the presto sql should be used as the language.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at the expected output you showed, based on the two input tables. Can you explain this?

Comment: Of cause. So I have the information of which current state id the given customer are in from the first table. In the second table i could then easily join current_state_id with state_id to get the current state name. To get the historical states I would have to follow the "replace_state_id", which is the tricky part.  Customer1 are currently in state_id=33, but have earlier been in state_id=22, which can be seen in table 2. Is it clear?

Comment: I get it now, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one option using a union.  The crux behind this query is that we generate a single logical `state_id` column to which we join the customer table.  This table contains both current and replace `state_id` values for a given state.

```
SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    t.state_created,
    t.state_name
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT state_id, state_name, state_created
    FROM Historical_state
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h1.state_id, h2.state_name, h2.state_created
    FROM Historical_state h1
    INNER JOIN Historical_state h2
        ON h1.replace_state_id = h2.state_id
) t
    ON c.current_state_id = t.state_id;
```

[image]

Here is a demo in MySQL, because Rextester does not support SQLite, but it at least shows that the query logic is correct.

### Demo

Comment: This works very well for all customers that have been in 1 or 2 states. Unfortunately it does not generalize to customers that have been in more than 2 states

Comment: I have answered the exact question you posed.  If you had other edge cases in mind, then you should have mentioned those.  I don't even know what you mean by "3>=states."  What does that mean?

Comment: Yeah I see. 
What I mean is that in my example there was only customers that have been in (maximum) two different states. In reality a customer could have been in an unknown number of states. Your solution do not account for this. I was not explicit about this and you indeed solved my question as it was. I will click that you solved it and post this problem better explained :)

Comment: You may ask a new question if you still need more help, but please show the real data behind the question.