# Recursively tracking state of customers with unknown number of states (Presto SQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have one table with the current `state_id` of my customers and another table holding all states and their `state_id`s, but without the corresponding `customer_id`.

However, the historical state table holds the information of which `state_id` it replaced. Hence, it should be possible to recursively track the states/journey of the customer.

Consider the following example:

"Customer" table:

```
customer_id    state_created      current_state_id
1              2017-11-09         33
2              2018-04-01         243
3              2018-07-10         254
```

"Historical_state" table:

```
state_name     replace_state_id   state_id           state_created
State1                            22                 2015-10-08
State1                            211                2017-06-28
State3                            254                2018-07-10
State6         211                226                2017-12-13
State4         226                243                2018-04-01
State5         22                 33                 2017-11-09
```

I am interested in getting the historical state information on every customer, ie. the following table:

```
customer_id    state_created      state_name       
1              2015-10-00         State1
1              2017-11-09         State5
2              2017-06-28         State1
2              2017-12-13         State6
2              2018-04-01         State4
3              2018-07-10         State3
```

So, for any `customer_id` I know the `current_state_id`. With this `state_id` I can, with `replace_state_id`, recursively track all the states a given customer have been in.

I want a table that shows all customers and all the states (with the `state_created` column) these customers have been in, historically. The number of states each customer have been in are not explicitly given.

The data is placed in AWS' Athena, so the presto sql should be used as the language.

Comment: No your former solution resulted in two historical states for customer_id=2. That is, it only shows that customer_id two have been in State6 and State4, but lacks State1. Similarly, if A customer historically have been in 4 states, say State1 State2, State3 and State4, then your code only accounts for the two most recent States for that given customer.

Comment: I see it now.  You're going to need to use a recursive query here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a recursive CTE here:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (state_id, state_name, state_created) AS (
    SELECT state_id, state_name, state_created
    FROM Historical_state
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h1.state_id, h2.state_name, h2.state_created
    FROM Historical_state h1
    INNER JOIN cte h2
        ON h1.replace_state_id = h2.state_id
)

SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    t.state_created,
    t.state_name
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON c.current_state_id = t.state_id
ORDER BY
    c.customer_id,
    t.state_created;
```

[image]

Again, as was the case in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823728/recursively-tracking-state-of-customers-presto-sql/51823991#51823991), I can't show a Rextester demo for SQLite, which doesn't support that dialect of SQL.  But, the demo below shows that the recursive CTE logic in fact works on SQL Server.

### Demo

Comment: Apparently, Athena does not support recursive queries. Connecting MySQL Workbench to Athena via a ODBC is also not a solution due to my Read only access, which denies me from making recursive queries as well.
Is there any other way around this problem?

Comment: @NicolaiIversen You don't need a recursive CTE per se; you may just do however many self joins are required to cover the entire chain, as my answer from yesterday was doing.  But, if you don't know this number, then the problem gets difficult.  The answer I gave is the preferred way of doing this on most databases.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for your help :)